# How to handle the forced download of zip file using JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, rest

I'm using a REST API with `POST` data. I'm creating a zip file and doing a forced download. I need to call that API by sending the required `POST` data using JQuery, which should then get the download. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this :
**HTML:**

```
<input type="button" class="list" value="Download ZipFile" id="download"/>
```

**JS :**

```
$("#download").click(function(){
  //this is the data when you send your request 
    var data = { yourKey1 :'something1', yourKey2:'something2'};

  // this is a fake response that we are assumming you got from ajax's response inside success call back 
  var response = {fileName:'yourFileName.zip' ,filePath : 'YouFilePath'};

  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'yourURL',
        data: data,
        success: function(response) {
           download(response);
       }
   }); 

});

var download = function (data){
  var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = data.filePath + data.fileName ;
    //below you can define a new name
    link.download = data.fileName;
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
}
```

**Example :** https://jsfiddle.net/3yjt4Lah/8/